# Using angular.js to set selected from a dynamic value in JSON files

Tags: json, angularjs

Forgive me if this is a newbie question. I'm very new to Angular.

I've looked everywhere for this, and while there are a lot of questions answered about setting a **default** selected option, I haven't found one where the selected option is set dynamically from values in a JSON file.

My controller looks like this:

```
peopleControllers.controller('PeopleListCtrl', ['$scope','PeopleList',
function($scope, PeopleList) {
    $scope.id = 'id';
    $scope.people = PeopleList.query();
    $scope.orderProp = 'name';
    $scope.comments = 'comments';
    $scope.department = 'department';
    $scope.departmentList = [
        {id : 1, name : "HR" },
        {id : 2, name : "Accounting"},
        {id : 3, name : "Marketing"}
    ];
}]);
```

**PeopleList** is a $resource that comes from a JSON file formatted like this:

```
[
{
    "id": "johnasmith",  
    "name": "John A. Smith",
    "department": "1",
    "comments": "Good worker"
},
{
    "id": "sarahqpublic",  
    "name": "Sarah Q. Public",
    "department": "2",
    "comments": "New hire"
},
{
    "id": "janedoe",  
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "department": "3",
    "comments": "Good resource for information"
}
]
...
```

And in the HTML, I have this:

```
ul class="people">
    <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
        <a href="#/people/{{people.id}}"><h3>{{people.name}}</h3></a>
        <p>{{people.comments}}</p>
        <select ng-model="department" ng-options="departmentList.name for department in departmentList track by department.id">
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The select statement populates with all the right info from departmentList, but its selected value ends up being blank. If I set a static value for $scope.department, like `$scope.department = $scope.departmentList[1];` (for "Accounting") it works perfectly. But it doesn't seem to be able to pull the department value from the JSON file.

I know I'm missing something simple and obvious. There have got to be other people who have already asked and had answered this question, so I'm sorry if this turns out to be a duplicate. But I'm really stymied right now.

Comment: Should be `ng-model="person.department"`

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Either way, the select gets properly populated, but the selected value is blank.

Comment: But what does that mean specifically?

Comment: I'm sorry, that wasn't very clear. I end up with a blank selection as the `selected` option, rather than the correct department. Looking at it in the console, the blank selection's value is "?".

Comment: Actually, you got me part of the way, too, so thank you! @Pankaj got me the rest of the way, but everyone who answered was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**From Docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)
>
> select as and track by Do not use select as and track by in the same
>   expression. They are not designed to work together.

Additionally as @Chrillewoodz suggested you need to convert the `string` to `number` for department `id`

**Markup**

```
<select ng-model="person.department" 
   ng-options="department.id as department.name for department in departmentList">
</select>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dVy3S5bodXSwOCsB70PE?p=preview)

Comment: I love you! That was it! Thank you, thank you, a million times thank you!

Comment: @GoodDamon Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You JSON file contains only strings which is causing you to search for the value `"3"` in the array instead of selecting `[3]`. So change your JSON to `department: 3` instead of `department: "3"` and so on.

Like this:

```
{
    "id": "johnasmith",  
    "name": "John A. Smith",
    "department": 1,
    "comments": "Good worker"
},
{
    "id": "sarahqpublic",  
    "name": "Sarah Q. Public",
    "department": 2,
    "comments": "New hire"
},
{
    "id": "janedoe",  
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "department": 3,
    "comments": "Good resource for information"
}
```

Also you should do `select ng-model="person.department"`.

Comment: I made the change in my JSON file and switched the ng-model, but I still end up with a blank default selection.

Comment: @Pankaj figured out the missing piece, but this got me part of the way, so thank you, too!

Comment: @Chrillewoodz +1 for the first part of solution.. Cheers

Comment: @PankajParkar Cheers :)